# How to use Facebook Application to write a notification to Users

Tags: facebook, posting

i'm developing an application for a university exam, using Appengine and Gwt (Google products) and i'd like to implement Facebook this way:
- give the ability to a FB user to login to the application through facebook (did this implementing the oAuth2.0 flow, so now i have the user's access token and his permissions)
- since the application is for being notified when a professor publishes some material for his course (this is all handled by appengine), i'd like to notify the user when a professor publishes some material, through a wall post or a note from my application in a way that it writes to the user something about the new published material.

I've been looking through EVERY single resource online, and couldn't find an answer: a lot of similar questions but no answers.

Writing the POST is not a problem, and for the moment i'm trying with the api graph explorer.
I manage to write on the user's wall/note as if he's writing himself or (if the user likes the application) write all the likers a wall post/note (but the same to everyone).

But i don't find a way to send personalized wall posts/notes to every user in response to some specific material published.
FB doesn't allow to do this because is considered spamming?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly post things to your user's wall as a way of notifying them - wall posts are intended to be things the user posts from within your app (for instance, they find something in your app interesting and choose to share it with their friends, so they click a 'Share' button).

You could try using an App-Generated Request (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests). This will increment the user's Bookmark Counter, and when they click on it they will enter your app and you can show them the latest news.

OR, you could ask for the 'email' permission for your app, and send the user an email notification when something is new.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply ;)
I used the email for notification now, but i wanted to try also the app-generated requests...but my application doesn't seem to have the bookmark to show the counter... how come?
Do i have to change some settings? Or write some code for that to show up?

Thanks

Comment: I believe that only apps which are "Apps on Facebook" (aka canvas apps) have the bookmark, so it's probably only relevant in this case. If your app is for an external web site, you could try directing users who use your app and visit Facebook often through a canvas version of your app that is exclusively intended for getting people onto your site.

Also, if you feel the questions has been answered, please just do me/the community a favor and click the green checkbox to 'accept' the answer. Thanks! Good luck.